# Laravel 5 - Why second parameter of env()

Tags: php, laravel, env

Almost every php files inside config folder has this function here -> env().
This function take 2 parameters like so :

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')
```

I know that the first parameter is to get the right line, but what's the meaning of the second parameter : smtp? I already provided the mail driver inside my .env file but I can't get it why is there 'smtp' inside env()

I looked around and nothing is talking about this. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that this is a function in laravel that simply wraps http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php or something similar. The second parameter is the value for the environmental variable itself. So in your case you're setting the `MAIL_DRIVER` environmental variable to be `smtp`

Comment: the documentation for the `env` function can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second value is the default used if Laravel can't find an environment variable with the given key. So if you do have a `MAIL_DRIVER` environment variable set, that one will be used. If you don't, Laravel will use `'smtp'` instead.

The same system is used for several other things Laravel does as well, for instance `trans()` and `Config::get()`.

Comment: Great! Thanks to you. I will be happy to accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Is the default parameter if not custom parameter is defined in the .env file

Answer (score 1):

It's the default parameter assumed by the framework if the value is not provided on the .env file.